# unrecognised selector sent to an instance causing application crash

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, static-libraries

I have created the static library which builds successfully,I have added .a file in the application where I want to use it. But application getting crashed the error while running the application "unrecognised selector sent to an instance". But if I include the static library source in the application I am not getting any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to link with library. Do not add source to app target, add library project to app project and then open build phases tab, add your static lib to target dependencies and link binary with libraries.

Comment: thanks for you help. i got resolved by adding linker flag -Obj in application which uses the static library